# It is not possible to automatically connect the bean from the user library.(Spring)

Tags: spring-boot, java-17

I use spring-boot (2.6.7).

the custom library is downloaded from private nexus repository and I see in classpath of project.

I have a custom library and I want to configure the bean. so that another component in the project automatically implements it to itself already configured.

- bean from library

```java
//library

public interface Helper<S,T> {

    T prepare(S messageMetaDto);
}
```

- implementation that bean in the library

```java
//library

@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HelperImpl
        implements Helper<MessageMetaDto, EmailDto<MessageDto>> {

    private final MessageConverter<InfoDto, MessageDto>  messageConverter;

 @Override
    public EmailDto<MessageDto> prepare(MessageMetaDto messageMetaDto) {
  ....
}

}
```

```java
//library

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmailDto<T> {

    private T message;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

}
```

- in myProject

```java
@Configuration
public class TemplateConfig {

    @Bean(name = "prepareMessage")
    public Helper<MessageMetaDto, EmailDto<MessageDto>> prepareMessage(MessageConverter<InfoDto, MessageDto> messageConverter){

        return new HelperImpl(messageConverter);
    }


    @Bean
    public MessageConverter<InfoDto, AzureMessageDto> messageConverter(){
        return new MessageConverterImpl();
    }
}
```

- the bean **Helper**  - > not found
- but the bean **MessageConverter** - has created.

  Why a bean with nested parameters is not created, but another one is created.

But after all, the integration tests when I ran them in the library were in order, such a complex generic did not affect ?

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

there was a duplicate data model

```java
//library

@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
public class EmailDto<T> {

    private T message;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

}
```

in the project . I removed it from the project, then the component from the library was normally initialized and added to the Application context.